# Ajax slide show extender does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I followed the tutorial from this link [Ajax Slide show extender](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/ajax-slideshowextender-control-sample.html)

My code is as follows

```
<div>
    <table style="border:Solid 3px #D55500; width:400px; height:400px" cellpadding="0"  
           cellspacing="0">
        <tr style="background-color:#D55500">
            <td style=" height:10%; color:White; font-weight:bold; font-size:larger"  
                align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="imgslides" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="400px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="lblimgdesc" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnPrevious" runat="server" Text="Prev" CssClass="button" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnPlay" runat="server" Text="Play" CssClass="button" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" CssClass="button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <ajax:SlideShowExtender runat="server" AutoPlay="true" ImageTitleLabelID="lblTitle"  
   ImageDescriptionLabelID="lblimgdesc" Loop="true"
   NextButtonID="btnNext" PreviousButtonID="btnPrevious" PlayButtonID="btnPlay"   
   PlayButtonText="Play" StopButtonText="Stop"
   TargetControlID="imgslides" SlideShowServicePath="Slideshow.asmx"   
   SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides"></ajax:SlideShowExtender>
```

and in my web service i have a file

```
[WebMethod]     
    public AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
    {
        string[] ImageNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(@"C:\Users\Mayer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Project1\Images\"));
        AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] photos = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[ImageNames.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ImageNames.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] file = ImageNames[i].Split('\\');
            photos[i] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("Images/" + file[file.Length - 1], file[file.Length - 1], "");
        }
        return photos;
    }
```

I have images folder but I cant see my slide show

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass relative address to `Server.MapPath`

It should be something like: `~\Project1\Project1\Images\` instead of the physical path:
  `C:\Users\Mayer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Project1\Images\`

> The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the
>   corresponding physical directory on the server.

From the docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Doesnt work..I have added a breakpoint...but debugger never reaches that breakpoint

Comment: Is service annotated by `ScriptService` attribute?